# Count Occurrences of a text in a file with a shell command

Tags: bash, shell

Question seems simple, but there is a twist here.
Consider a file with with data :

> A,B
>   A,C
>   A,D
>   D,A
>   C,A
>   B,A

Here, I need a bash command which gives the count of occurrences taking

> A,B
>   B,A

as a single count. Hence total count for this example should be 3 and not 6.

Comment: So...  we should write your assignment?  What have you tried?  How can we **help** (not write it for you)?

Comment: @Huzaifa, always show your sample input and expected output in CODE TAGS(not in quote tags) please. Your expected output is not clear here so please do mention it. Also we all are here to learn so always add your efforts which you made to solve this problem to solve to your post too.

Comment: @Huzaifa, also try to select answers as correct answers(I saw none of your posts are a complete thread) so do that to make a post complete.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : Noted.. Henceforth will mark. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '!(($1,$2) in a){a[$1,$2];a[$2,$1];c++} END{print c}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same as the other answers but it figures out the order of the components for hashing:

```
$ awk -F, '!(($(($1<$2)+1),$(($2<=$1)+1)) in a){a[$(($1<$2)+1),$(($2<=$1)+1)];c++}END{print c}' file
3
```

Explained

```
$ awk -F, '
!( ( $(($1<$2)+1), $(($2<=$1)+1) ) in a ) {
    a[$(($1<$2)+1),$(($2<=$1)+1)]
    c++
}
END { print c }' file
```

`$1<$2` is either 0 or 1, therefore `($1<$2)+1` is 1 or 2 and `$(($1<$2)+1)` either `$1` or `$2`. Same applies to the other component `$(($2<=$1)+1)`, it's either `$2` or `$1`. So, it's referencing `a[$1,$2]` or `a[$2,$1]`. Tested with:

```
A,A
A,A
```

That `<=` could be just `<` in the latter component, leading to `a[$1,$1]` if `$1==$2`.